# Complex Queries in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on an application that uses `DynamoDB`.

Is there a way where I can create a GSI with multiple attributes. My aim is to query the table with a query of following kind:

```
(attrA.val1 === someVal1 AND attrB.val2 === someVal2 AND attrC.val3 === someVal3) 
OR (attrA.val4 === someVal4 AND attrB.val5 === someVal5 AND attrC.val6 === someVal6)
```

I am aware we can use `Query` when we have the Key Attribute and when Key Attribute is unknown we can use `Scan` operations. I am also aware of GSI if we need to query with non-key attributes. But I need some help in this scenario. Is there a way to model GSI to suit the above query.

Comment: Do you mean what wanted the items on GSI only when the above condition is satisfied? This is very much similar to view on RDBMS.

Comment: I am trying to find out rows from my dynamobd table that satisfies the said condition. I won't mind if it is from the table or from the index. but the rows should satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 3):

I have the below item (i.e. data) on my `Movies` tables. The below query `params` works fine for me.

You can add the third attribute as present in the OP. It should work fine.

DynamoDB does support the complex condition on `FilterExpression`.

**Query table based on some condition:-**

```
var table = "Movies";

var year_val = 1991;
var title = "Movie with map attribute";

var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditionExpression : 'yearkey = :hkey and title = :rkey',
    FilterExpression : '(records.K1 = :k1Val AND records.K2 = :k2Val) OR (records.K3 = :k3Val AND records.K4 = :k4Val)',    
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':hkey' : year_val,
        ':rkey' : title,
        ':k3Val' : 'V3',
        ':k4Val' : 'V4',        
        ':k1Val' : 'V1',
        ':k2Val' : 'V2'

    }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));      
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

    }
});
```

**My Data:-**

[image]

**Result:-**

```
GetItem succeeded: {
  "Items": [
    {
      "title": "Movie with map attribute",
      "yearkey": 1991,
      "records": {
        "K3": "V3",
        "K4": "V4",
        "K1": "V1",
        "K2": "V2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Count": 1,
  "ScannedCount": 1
}
```

Comment: Perfectly fine. But my problem here is; How do I model my Table or GSI as I  am unaware of the values that I have to match in the `KeyConditionExpression`. I can use the above example and pass my query as the filter expression. But still, I need `KeyConditionExpression`.

Comment: Well, you have not provided any info in the OP regarding your entire model. The OP just asks whether you can write complex queries using DynamoDB. You have to provide all the relevant attributes and query access pattern and ask how can you design the GSI.